# A better way to 'transfer' data from one ID to another, then delete the first ID, from the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with employee data which include employee_id and supervisor_id. Now I want to delete a certain employee, but how do I transfer the employees that are managed by him to his supervisor?

So, I have tried this way but I feel it is abit "hard coded", hence is there a better way to implement this?

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE
SET sup_id = 001
WHERE sup_id = 002;
```

And then delete the employee.
Thankyou.

Comment: update your question add  a clear data sample and the expected  result

Comment: If you are hoping that a delete could somehow trigger the update then you will be disappointed. You might consider using a procedure to update then delete.

Comment: The 2-step process makes perfect sense to me. The only suggestion from me might be using a transaction to make sure it doesn't leave any dirty data behind if it fails halfway.

Comment: Its "Hard coded" when you hard code the values - is this a question about how to paramaterise the query? The login of Update-then-delete is correct. Just wrap it in a stored proc and a transaction.